# Java ClassNotFoundException on the first launch

Tags: java, jboss

everytime i make a clean install on jboss and launch our system i'm getting a "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException", but after that if i stop and them launch again the error doesn't appear. Any ideas ?

```
      public <T> T compilaNoCache(String codigo, String fonteBase, String realPath) throws Exception {
    // Compila o código..
    String[] result = this.compilar(codigo, fonteBase, realPath);

    String erro = result[0];
    String nomeCls = result[1];

    // Se existir algum erro lança uma RegraNegocioException
    if (!erro.isEmpty()) {
        throw new RegraNegocioException(erro);
    }

    // Cria uma instância do código, e armazena no Map
    Object objInstancia = Class.forName(nomeCls).newInstance();
    mapaCodigo.put(codigo.hashCode(), objInstancia);

    return (T) objInstancia;
}
```

Stacktrace :

```
15:46:39,561 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-7) java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: br.com.dataeasy.docflow4.web.code.classeDin0 from [Module "deployment.docflow4-web.war:main" from Service Module Loader]

15:46:39,574 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-7)    at br.com.dataeasy.docflow4.bus.negocio.impl.CampoValidadorBO.carregarValidadores(CampoValidadorBO.java:202)

15:46:39,575 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-7)    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

15:46:39,575 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-7)    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)

15:46:39,575 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-7)    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

15:46:39,575 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-7)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)

15:46:39,575 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-7)    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318)

15:46:39,575 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-7)    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)

15:46:39,575 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-7)    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)

15:46:39,575 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-7)    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)

15:46:39,575 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-7)    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)

15:46:39,575 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-7)    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)

15:46:39,575 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-7)    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy397.carregarValidadores(Unknown Source)

15:46:39,575 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-7)    at br.com.dataeasy.docflow4.web.DocflowLoadListener.contextInitialized(DocflowLoadListener.java:236)

15:46:39,575 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-7)    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392)

15:46:39,575 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-7)    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850)

15:46:39,575 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-7)    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90)

15:46:39,575 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-7)    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)

15:46:39,575 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-7)    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)

15:46:39,575 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-7)    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)

15:46:39,575 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-7)    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)

15:46:39,575 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-7)    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

15:46:39,575 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-7) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: br.com.dataeasy.docflow4.web.code.classeDin0 from [Module "deployment.docflow4-web.war:main" from Service Module Loader]

15:46:39,575 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-7)    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)

15:46:39,575 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-7)    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)

15:46:39,575 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-7)    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)

15:46:39,575 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-7)    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)

15:46:39,575 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-7)    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)

15:46:39,575 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-7)    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)

15:46:39,575 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-7)    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)

15:46:39,575 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-7)    at br.com.dataeasy.acs.bus.ctr.negocio.impl.CodigoExecutarBO.compilaNoCache(CodigoExecutarBO.java:123)

15:46:39,575 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-7)    at br.com.dataeasy.docflow4.bus.negocio.impl.CampoValidadorBO.carregarValidadores(CampoValidadorBO.java:198)

15:46:39,575 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-7)    ... 20 more
```

Comment: 1) please show the exception stacktrace. 2) when is the above code called (during application server startup)?

Comment: what's the command line that you are executing? and paste the output of %CLASSPATH% on windows or $CLASSPATH on *nix system.

Comment: As far as I can see, your code is generating `.class` files at runtime. Small wonder it doesn't work with JBoss and its class loader.

Comment: Here the stacktrace and yes it's called during the application startup